# Particles Pattern Control

Tags: particles

i am trying to get that particle pattern, its making a half circle orientation depending on where it is, how i could acheve this without making a lot of particle systems with different direction, like using a function to describe the particles orientation?[image: Pattern]

Comment: You can use image based textures to control particle properties like length and density